# Why is it a bad idea to have long httpResponse timeouts?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config, timeout, httpresponse

I've found that you can adjust the httpResponse timeout in web.config for a .net project.

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestValidationType="SampleRequestValidator" maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

My question is this:  Why would it be a bad idea to have a really long timeout set and what should the ideal upper limit be?  The reason I need to adjust this value is because of the large amount of time it takes to compress large files before they can be streamed to the client browser.  Appreciate the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not in control of the entire request chain.  The browser, and any any proxy servers between the browser and your server, may impose their own timeout values on the connection, which may be shorter than yours.  I would look take a look at making your processing asynchronous and not tying up a single connection waiting for a long-running operation to complete.

Comment: By asynchronous, do you mean like a "long-polling" type solution in which the browser creates an AJAX connection to wait until the file is ready to be downloaded?  I was thinking of using SignalR, perhaps.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I have been using SignalR for things like this lately, works great.